# MongoDB: How to count the number of documents for every category?

Tags: mongodb

I am currently trying to find the number of ratings per a hotel. It is in this 
[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkgJP.png).

I tried running the following:

> db.reviews.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{hotel:'$HotelInfo.Name'}, totalReviews: {$sum:1}}}])

The result of course just gave me the name of each hotel followed by a 1. How do I correctly display what I want to show?